# Inserting a single hyperlink in LaTeX

Tags: hyperref, urls

I want to insert a single URL that is clickable in the resulting PDF file I produce, but when I use the `hyperref` package, that turns every use of `\ref`, the table of contents, etc. into a hyperlink in the document.  I just want the one URL to be a hyperlink.  Any simple solutions?

Answer (score 9):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides a hyper-link-less referencing through `\ref*` rather than `\ref`. On a case-by-case basis you can use use this. Or, a global alternative could be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldref\ref% 
  \def\ref{\oldref*}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{one} This is section~\ref{one}. \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\section{Another section}\label{two} This is section~\ref{two}.
\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\ref` to `\ref*` is delayed until `\AtBeginDocument`.

Answer (score 5):

Does this help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
  \let\oldurl\url
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \let\linkurl\url
  \let\url\oldurl
\begin{document}
  \url{http://google.com}
  \linkurl{http://goo.gl}
\end{document}
```